# Error 0x80073701 al intentar activar HyperV

Tags: android, android-studio, windows, windows10, instalacion

Estoy intentando activar HyperV para la virtualizacion en Android Studio con ryzen. Cuando lo activo desde windows features, me da el error **0x80073701**, y cuando intento usar `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All` en la powershell, me tira

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : The referenced assembly could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

Tambien intente con `DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V`, pero me lanza un error **14081**.
Ciertamente no entiendo la razon de esto, puesto que hace un tiempo lo intente y funcionaba. Y lo que he podido encontrar en google no me ha funcionado. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida

Comment: Hola, ¿Qué versión de Windows usas?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la versión de compilación? Para ver la versión de compilación pulsas a la vez las teclas de `Windows + "R"` y, después, escribes la palabra `"winver" ` (sin las comillas). Y presionas enter.

Comment: Version 1809 (OS Build 17763. 1577)

Comment: ¿Puede ejecutar estos comandos en este orden y al finalizar todo tratar de habilitar HyperV?

 1. Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup 
 2. sfc /scannow
 3. Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth 
 4. sfc /scannow

Comment: Me salta Error: 14081

The referenced assembly could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer esto es un problema que se presenta aleatoriamente en diferentes dispositivos con Windows 10.

Esto puede ser por causa de archivos corruptos o faltantes en el sistema el cual no permite que se ejecuten ciertas características. Como se habla acá en [este foro](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f319fdb-768e-4ce0-abcd-54498fe47e56/hyperv-service-cant-be-enabled-error-0x80073710-kb3194798) de Microsoft.

Después de haber probado los siguientes comandos sin ningún resultado positivo

> 1. Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
> 2. sfc /scannow
> 3. Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
> 4. sfc/scannow

Las soluciones más prometedoras son las siguientes:

> Actualizar Windows a través de Windows Update.

o

> Reparar el sistema operativo usando una imagen ISO

en [este enlace](https://trucoswindows.net/reparar-windows-10/) podrás ver un tutorial de como reparar Windows 10